# Execute PHP code using javascript confirm method

Tags: javascript, php

I know PHP runs on the server while JS runs on the client, but I also know it's possible to do this during input validation:

```
<?php
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.alert('Please enter a valid number.');
window.location.href = '/index.html';</script>";
exit;  
?>
```

So I'm wondering, is it possible for me to use the Javascript confirm method to do something like this on button click:

```
<?php
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">var q = confirm('Are you sure you want to exit?.');
    //if q == true {  //ok is clicked
      window.location.href = '/page_x.php';
    } else { //cancel is clicked
      window.location.href = '/index.php';</script>";
    exit;  
    ?>
```

I don't know much about Javascript. I just want a simple way to execute PHP code on button click, but using Javascript confirm dialog. When the button is clicked, it asks the user whether they wish to continue (or something) or not. If they click Ok, they are taken to some php page. If they click Cancel, nothing happens, the dialog just exits.

I have searched round the web (even on StackOverFlow) for a solution, and everyone points to Ajax or JQuery, and I don't know how to use either.

So I was thinking in the line of using something as simple as the pseudo code I posted above, but I don't know if it's legal to do that, and even if it is, I don't know how.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Technically there's nothing wrong with what you posted. What do you need to know?

Comment: I have edited the post to reflect my problem

Comment: Wouldn't you have gotten the answer quicker (and more authoritatively) by typing the cope into a web page and testing it than typing your code in here?

Answer (score 0):

Well first, the confirm is a JS function so you can only treat it on JS level. If you are willing execute anything php from JS after confirmation you need to make an AJAX call.

Although, everything you have written in that answer is correct on technical level.

```
 echo "
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
 var q = confirm('Are you sure you want to exit?.');
    if q == true 
      window.location.href = '/page_x.php'; //THIS IS JAVASCRIPT so it is fine
    else
      window.location.href = '/index.php'; //THIS IS JAVASCRIPT so it is fine
</script>";
```

Comment: Can you please explain to me how to make an AJAX call to run a PHP function when the Javascript Ok button is clicked? I have not used AJAX before and everyone else seems to understand it so well that it's difficult to find any place where it's well explained for dummies.

Comment: @Valkay The easiest way by far to make ajax calls is to include jQuery and use its simple functions. For example, if you just want to get the result of a PHP script, you'd do: $.get( "something.php", function( data ) {
  //do something with the data here (the data is the output of the srcipt)
});

Don't be afraid of including jQuery either - it is as simple as putting <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> at the beginning of your page